# Docker output of exec command in detach mode

Tags: docker, dockerpy

I'm trying to start a jar file inside a running container. 
In order to do this I use this command `docker exec -t -d [containerID] java -jar jarname.jar`. 
The command is successfully executed but I am unable to see its output. 
Docker allocates a new tty in the host but how can I see its output?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

How about removing the `-d` flag, then you will get the output on stdout.

Can use shell redirection and backgrounding on the docker command if needed.

I would also remove the '-t' flag unless your Java program specifically needs a tty.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, was thinking of 'docker run'; have removed old answer and tried again.

Comment: I do not understand why with -d flag I can't see its output. I will try to explain better what I want to do. I'm using docker-py API to run this command inside a running container using openstack and novadocker driver, I call the execute method (in docker-py) but if I set detach to False I will get a timeout error because POST request never return contrary to docker API documentation [link](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.15/#exec-start). I do not know if it is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The docker command-line communicates with the docker daemon over a socket; the daemon starts the new child process. The cli needs to arrange to fetch output from the new process over that socket.  I just checked the Docker source code, and '-d' turns off that log-file fetching.

Comment: You might find looking at the docker daemon log helpful, and maybe turning on its debug mode.

Comment: Re 'POST never returns' - see [docs for attach](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.15/#attach-to-a-container) - this is how the process' output is returned to you if you use the API.

Comment: Ok you are absolutely right but my problem is that the jar never returns so also the POST request never returns. I want to start the command inside the container and after obtain its output with logs API.

Comment: Does it work if you exec something like 'ps' instead of the jar?

Comment: Yes it works also if I exec a jar that finishes at a certain point and the POST request returns its output as for attach stream. But I want to execute a jar that never finishes, detach from it and retrieve its output only when I want.

Comment: Exec'd processes are very like containers - I suspect you can run it in detatched mode and [fetch the logs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.15/#get-container-logs) when you want using the 'exec id' you used to start it.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I hoped that this was the solution but it is not. In [this image](http://imgur.com/xwJNvU8) you can see that after call exec docker tries to attach stdout but since the program never ends the exec call will never return.

Comment: You need to set detached:true

Comment: This happens also with detach=True, for this reason I do not know if it is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.